# Is there any workaround to get celery task result if celery result backend is disabled?

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

I need to get a result of celery task but there is no `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` in the project I'm working on.

```
|  -------------- celery@e465919cc343 v5.2.3 (dawn-chorus)
| --- ***** ----- 
| -- ******* ---- Linux-5.19.0-43-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2023-06-13 18:45:02
| - *** --- * --- 
| - ** ---------- [config]
| - ** ---------- .> app:         cms:0x7feb41db9490
| - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis-xxxxx:6379/0
| - ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
| - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
| -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
| --- ***** -----
```

It means an expression like

```
task = my_task.delay(keyword=domain).get()
```

won't ever work.

What can I do? Is there any workaround?

Everything I tried failed to work. It seems that it's impossible according to Celery documentation.